# Authorization header in img src link

Tags: javascript, html, jwt

I have a API that uses JWT for authentication. I am using this API for a Vue app. I am trying to display an image in the app using

```
<img src="my/api/link" />
```

But the API expects `Authorization` header with JWT in it.

Can I add headers to browser request like this?

Is there any way around it (using JS) or should I change the API itself?

Comment: The API should deliver the image as a static asset. This shouldn't require the JWT Authorization.

Comment: @MaKobi That's a big assumption about the use case. OP, some related reading and potential solutions in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096744/how-should-i-load-images-if-i-use-token-based-authentication

Comment: I need jwt authorization for images because they are private and only authenticated users should be able to see them

Comment: You can use [vue-auth-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-auth-image) plugin in case you develop with Vue.js

Comment: to @Marc: _"..is ... a design flaw that JWTs aren't just normal cookies.."_ it is neither a HTTP header. And **It is possible to store  JWT in cookies**, but be aware of the related security threats (one can start reading about this from this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27067251/1115187).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can not perform authentication on images which are directly used as href in img tag. If you really want this type of authentication on your images, then it's better to fetch them using ajax and then embed in your html.

Comment: To add on this answer: you cannot even manually/forcefully add the header in your service worker `fetch` handler. It will get removed before the actual network request is made.

Comment: A link would be nice

Comment: @Tapas What about with cookies?

Answer (score 13):

By default browsers are sending cookies.
You can prevent cookie sending in `fetch` if you set header's `{credentials: 'omit'}`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials)

Full `fetch` example:

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
let headers = {};

if (user && user.token) {
  headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token };
} 

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    credentials: 'omit'
};

let req = await fetch(`${serverUrl}/api/v2/foo`, requestOptions);
if (req.ok === true) {
...
```

Now, when you are login in, in your website, the webapp could save 
to credentials into *both* localStorage and cookie.
Example:

```
let reqJson = await req.json();
// response is: {token: 'string'}
//// login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
if (reqJson.token) {
    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({token: reqJson.token}));
    document.cookie = `token=${reqJson.token};`; //set the cookies for img, etc
}
```

So your webapp uses localStorage, just like your smartphone application. 
Browser gets all the static contents (img, video, a href) by sending cookies by default.

On the server side, you can copy the cookie to authorization header, if there is none.

Node.js+express example:

```
.use(function(req, res, next) { //function setHeader
  if(req.cookies && req.headers &&
     !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(req.headers, 'authorization') &&
     Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(req.cookies, 'token') &&
     req.cookies.token.length > 0
   ) {
    //req.cookies has no hasOwnProperty function,
    // likely created with Object.create(null)
    req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.cookies.token.slice(0, req.cookies.token.length);
  }
  next();
})
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: When I tried this one it's giving error on requestOptions

Comment: This is a clever solution: map jwt to a proper web standard (cookies) on the client and unmap them on the backend!

Comment: Good solution indeed. As a reminder, you have to add the cookie-parser middleware to express.js for this to work. Otherwise, req.cookies will be undefined

Answer (score 13):

You can use a Service Worker to intercept the `img` fetchs and add the `Authorization` header with the JWT token before hitting the server. Described in:

- https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2021/01/06/adding-headers-to-image-request-using-service-workers/
- [https://www.twelve21.io/how-to-access-images-securely-with-oauth-2-0/#:~:text=4.%20USE%20SERVICE%20WORKERS](https://www.twelve21.io/how-to-access-images-securely-with-oauth-2-0/#:%7E:text=4.%20USE%20SERVICE%20WORKERS)

Answer (score 8):

This is my solution based on Tapas' answer and this question [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html):

```
let jwtHeader = {headers: { Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpX..."}
let r = await axios.get(`/path/image`, {...jwtHeader, responseType:"arraybuffer"});
let d = Buffer.from(r.data).toString('base64');
let a = document.createElement('img');

a.src = `data:image/png;base64, ${d}`;
a.width = 300;
a.height = 300;
document.getElementById("divImage").appendChild(a);
```

In this case the html would have a <div id="divImage">

Comment: It can be simplified by adding the token to authorization headers (`axios.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + access_token`), than you don't need to append it to the urls (just check it on the server). I've used this before; the problem is that it feels noticeably slower then the native browser implementation `<img />`. (Haven't done any benchmarks, though.)

Comment: Buffer is not available in the browser, it is only available in Nodejs

Answer (score 6):

A workaround I often use is by leveraging a so-called nonce API endpoint. When calling this endpoint from the authenticated client, a short living string (could be a guid) is generated (for instance 30 seconds) and returned. Server-side you could of course add current user data to the nonce if you wish.

The nonce is then added to the image's query string and be validated server-side. The cost of this workaround is an extra API call.The main purpose of the workaround however is an increased security warrantee. Works like a charm ;) .

Answer (score 1):

There is another one method adds headers to HTTP request. Is it "Intercept HTTP requests". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests

Comment: Note: this approach works only in the context of firefox browser extensions, it can't be used in a webpage script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>测试获取图片</title>
        <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="test-img" src="" />
        <script>
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1/appApi/profile/cust/idcard/2021/12/30/533eed96-da1b-463b-b45d-7bdeab8256d5.jpg', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('token', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NDA5MTg1NTgsInVzZXJpZCI6IjMxIn0.TQmQE9E1xQwvVeAWRov858W2fqYpSMxZPCGlgvtcUDc');
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        request.onload = function(e) {
            var data = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
            var base64 = btoa(raw);
            var src = "data:image;base64," + base64;
        
            document.getElementById("test-img").src = src;
        };
        
        request.send();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="/api/images/yourimage.jpg?token=here-your-token">
```

In the backend you validate JWT from queryparam.

Comment: But then your token is sent in plain text, isn't it?

Comment: @ShafiqueJamal even if you include JWT in HTTP header it is still sent in plaintext. HTTPS is always a requirement when working with access token and the like from browser

Comment: I don't recommend this, the token is like a password, if your user copies it and then gives it to someone else then they can see the image.  If the user is malicious they can then use that token to get more information from the original user.

Comment: The JWT is in a cookie, or in a localstorage. If the user is malicious the can then user that token in any moment. Then the JWT is not the problem.

Comment: @Nagi With https your headers are also encrypted so they are not in plaintext as long as you use https.

Comment: @Mike sure, that's why I wrote HTTPS is required.

Comment: Possible risk: user rightclicks the image and opens it in another tab on a public computer. He leaves the computer. The attacker enter te computer and starts typing the base url (which is not secret) which is autocompleted by the browser with the param containing the jwt.

Comment: As @Exocomp is saying this is unsecure, the developer can improve the security if he reduces the token scope.

Comment: @motia There are absolutely no security improvements in reducing token scopes since user's privacy is still at risk. As a rule of thumb, never make an assumption on security-related concepts.