# Laravel passport – how can I check the validity of refresh token (while not revoking it)?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport, cookie-httponly

Using Laravel Passport, how can I check if a **refresh token** is still valid?

I'm not asking about the **access token**: that one I can verify by requesting any rout implementing the `Route::middleware(auth:api)->get('any-protected-route', function () { return true });`

I know how to use it to request a new access and refresh tokens (querying `oauth/tokens`), but it will **revoke the current one**.

Use case: I have a refresh token stored as `HttpOnly ✓ cookie`, and I'd like to use it to validate requests for static resources (native `<img src="…">` or `background-image: url(…)`, because it is being sent by browser with every request. But I don't know how to validate it (non-destructively) in the Controller.

(I am aware of the [access tokens as a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642960/authorization-header-in-img-src-link) solution, but I'd rather avoid it due to possible security issues).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check the validity of a Refresh Token, the purpose of these tokens is not to demonstrate that the user has a session, the only purpose of these tokens is to generate a new Access Token that can be used against your API and will validate if the user has a valid session.

If the refresh token is invalid, it won't generate a new access token.