# Blazor ASP.NET Core with JWT Authentication Signed Image or File URLs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an authenticated `Blazor` `WebAssembly` application whereby I nee to add in the ability to show and download files that contain sensitive information and so cannot be added to a public URL.

I have tried the using [Toolbelt.Blazor.HttpClientInterceptor](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.HttpClientInterceptor), to intercept and add the JWT to the header. But his does not intercept call made via `src` attributes in `img` or `iframe` tags.

I have also tried using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, manually adding in the JWT token to the header and tsetting the `img` or `iframe` `src` through the `razor.cs` however this seems to slow down blazors responsiveness considerable when loading (even though it is done through `async`/`await`).

I also want to be able to add in download links to files, for which I am not sure how to achieve this with httpclient?

From reading the following link;

[Token-Based Authentication Image URLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096744/how-should-i-load-images-if-i-use-token-based-authentication)

The recommended way is to create an anonymous endpoint for access with a GUID. However, I am unsure how I would generate the GUID safely and check it validity? Are there any nuget packages that help with this type of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try streaming the file with Javascript blobs. It's possible to create a unique one-time temporary url and it should be a safe option.