# windows 10 app development - Mediaplayer

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-media-player

I am using below code to play mp3 file from some url (https://domailname/a.mp3), this server required jwt token for authenticating the request.

how can i play the audio from any url which requires authentication

```
 System.Uri manifestUri = new Uri("https://domailname/a.mp3");
        mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(manifestUri);

        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put the token in the URL as a query parameter if under under the following circumstances described on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722952/is-it-safe-to-put-a-jwt-into-the-url-as-a-query-parameter-of-a-get-request).

`System.Uri manifestUri = new Uri("https://domailname/a.mp3/?jwt=jwttoken");`

[`MediaSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource) instance can create from [`AdaptiveMediaSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.streaming.adaptive.adaptivemediasource). If the media is adaptive source you may try to create a `AdaptiveMediaSource` by `CreateFromUriAsync(Uri, HttpClient)` method firstly. Put the token as value of  Authorization Header using the bear schema, and add the header to `HttpClient` by  the `DefaultRequestHeaders` property. For this you may reference the [scenario 3](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming/cs/Scenario3_RequestModification.xaml.cs) of `AdaptiveStreaming` official sample.